# Passing XSL file in classpath to XSLT Transformer

Tags: xml, eclipse, xslt, classpath, mule

I am trying to pass the XSL file which is located in the classpath to Mule XSL-T transformer in my flow.  Bit it is giving me error.

```
<mule-xml:xslt-transformer
maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5"
xsl-file="classpath:xslt/Person_Extractor.xsl">
</mule-xml:xslt-transformer>
```

Given below is the error shown in Eclipse console when I tried to run this application.

```
********************************************************************************

2013-01-18 15:00:00,596 ERROR [main] mule.MuleServer (MuleServer.java:474) - 
********************************************************************************
* A Fatal error has occurred while the server was running:                     *
* Unable to load resource classpath:xslt/Person_Extractor.xsl                  *
* (java.io.IOException)                                                        *
*                                                                              *
* The error is fatal, the system will shutdown                                 *
********************************************************************************
```

I tried all the different combinations like

```
classpath:/xslt/Person_Extractor.xsl
classpath:\xslt\Person_Extractor.xsl
```

But no luck.

When I give the full physical path of the file it works fine.

```
<mule-xml:xslt-transformer
maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5"
xsl-file="c:\EWS\MyMuleProj\src\main\resources\xslt\Person_Extractor.xsl">
</mule-xml:xslt-transformer>
```

Please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs say xsl-file "can be a path on the local file system or on the classpath", so have you tried without the `classpath:`, i.e. `xsl-file="xslt/Person_Extractor.xsl"`?

Comment: @user1760178 it's on the mulesource site, I just googled `mule xslt-transformer` to find the right page.

Comment: I got it. I looked into the Mule-xml jar to go through the details.